# Що в нього, що з ним, що про нього тощо

Tags: граматика

Як можна описати таку граматичну конструкцію?

- Я зустрів дівчину, що з нею ми були познайомилися місяць тому (що з
  нею — з якою)
- Вона написала книжку, що в ній багато цікавих історій
  (що в ній — у якій)
- Це той коментар, що про нього ми розмовляли (що
  про нього — про який)
- Підійшов майстер, що від нього я дізнався про
  матеріали, які варто використовувати (що від нього — від якого)

Чи можна десь прочитати правила її застосування й приклади? Чи правильно я розумію, що це абсолютно нормальна літературна мова, але просто таку конструкцію нині не дуже багато людей вживає?

Також цікавить питання, чи може бути після що конструкція не з двох слів (суто прийменник із займенником), а інші конструкції з займенником, які можуть складатися і з більшої кількості слів?

Наприклад:

Міст, достатньо близько до якого росте дерево

Як сказати таку ж саму фразу, але з що?

Міст, що достатньо близько до нього росте дерево

Так правильно?

Comment: Мені теж це дуже цікаво. (Інтуїтивно мені здавалося, що так частіше пишуть західні автори, ніж наддніпрянські. Бачив випадки, коли редактори викорчовували ці конструкції, але не мав нагоди спитати чому, можливо, це були суто стильові забаганки конкретних редакторів.)

Comment: Схоже на творення прикметників способом переходу з одніє частини мови до іншої, які в підрядній частині речення набувають форму прислівника

Comment: @RomanMikhol, проблема в тому, що я навіть не знаю, як лаконічно «обізвати» це явище, аби знайти щось про нього в пошукових системах :).

Comment: @Sasha дещо є про підрядні зґясувальні речення, які залежать від вказівного займенніка: https://miyklas.com.ua/p/ukrainska-mova/9-klas/skladnopidriadne-rechennia-43534/spr-z-pidriadnimi-z-iasuvalnimi-319759/re-5a40ea6d-536b-4af1-a797-2f29ac2dfd1d , https://disted.edu.vn.ua/courses/learn/4524 .

Comment: @RomanMikhol, може, я чогось не розумію, але за цими посиланнями я бачу про загальний випадок, а не «той, що його». За першим посиланням я навіть не бачу жодного такого прикладу (за другим є «Уся наша планета оповита невидимими шляхами, що ними мандрують слова (А. Коваль)»).

Comment: Відповідь: "Міст, поруч з яким росте дерево." або "Дерево, що росте біля мосту."

Comment: Дещо схоже запитання: [«Наскільки типовою є конструкції виду „що ним/нею/ними“ замість „яким/якою/якими“?»](/q/6918).

Answer (score 2):

У [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/shho) я не знайшов прикладів вживання цієї конструкції. Але маю догадку, що це така застаріла або формальна конструкція, котра має те ж значення, що й займенний "який". Звісно, це лише припущення, але мені це якось нагадує чеський займенник [jenž](https://cs.wiktionary.org/wiki/jen%C5%BE). Він також відмінюється, але для вживання не використовує займенник "що".

У чеській jenž має [книжний та застарілий характер](http://illidans4.blogspot.com/2017/06/ktery-jenz.html). Утім, якщо прочитати статті кінця 19-го початку 20-го століття "Наша мова" (чеськ. Naše řeč), дізнаємося, що [jenž використовується у підрядних означальних реченнях](http://nase-rec.ujc.cas.cz/archiv.php?art=198) для опису іменника, через що цей займенник пишуть як правило після іменника — а který (укр. котрий, який) має відтінок з'ясування, бо первісно це питальний займенник. Проводячи паралелі з українською мовою, jenž має те ж значення, що і "який", тобто придає певні власності, описує іменник. А který має теж значення, що й "котрий", тобто уточнює який саме (напр. серед множини), коли невідомо який саме є іменник.

Сьогодні ж, чеська мова використовує jenž, як уже було зазначено, у формальній мові. Частіше зустрічаються два слова: jaký та který, які мають ті ж значенння, що російські "какой" та "который". Таким чином, který перейняв значення jenž.

Не хочу морочити Вам голову чеською - звісно, що свою мову за чужою не можна точно досліджувати, але це може бути Вам такимось повштовхом у дослідженні).